# Why does Vimeo iframe flicker when clicking anywhere on the page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have created a simple filter that loads a Vimeo `iframe`. This is inside of an `ng-repeat` directive. Everything works fine, except that the iframe flickers whenever I click anywhere on the webpage. This also occurs each time I press a key (happens on "keyup") in a `textarea` or `input` field. It's a bit strange, because nothing else on the page is flickering - only the `iframe` that contains the Vimeo video. Here is the code I have:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myAppCtrl"> 
        <div ng-repeat="item in items">
            <div id="{{item.video.code}}">{{item.video.code | vimeo}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.filter('vimeo', function() {
    return function(vimeoID) {
        var data = '<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/' + vimeoID + '" width="360" height="270" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen><\/iframe>';
        $('#' + vimeoID).html(data);
    };
});

myApp.controller("myAppCtrl",function($scope){
    // sample data
    var items = [
        {
            text : 'Hello World",
            video : {
                source : 'Vimeo',
                code : '101468694'
            }
        },
        {
            text : 'Hello People",
            video : {
                source : 'Vimeo',
                code : '35375393'
            }
        }
    ];

    $scope.items = items;
});

Any ideas on why this is happening?
```

Comment: If you start the video playing, does it reset to the start when it flickers? Perhaps the iframe is being refreshed.

Comment: Yes. If I click play on the video, then click anywhere on the webpage, the video will stop playing. It appears to reload the iframe. Why might this be occurring?

Comment: Hard to say, presumably something has registered a click handler. I'd try adding a breakpoint inside the `function(vimeoID)` function, and have a look at the call stack. Possibly Angular is miss-detecting that the array of items has changed, and is re-rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Use "ngx-embed-video"

Click [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-embed-video)!
This works with https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-embed-video-example stackblitz.com/ngx-embed-video-example as well.

Comment: please, share your guidance as text.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please check again this link is very useful.